# Expected number of rounds to finish a game.

Tags: probability, expected-value

$n$ cards are arranged in a line, starting with card $1$ on the far left and ending with card $n$ on the far right. You are playing the following game: starting at card 1, you pick a card to the right at random and advance to this card. You repeat this behavior until you reach card $n$. What is the expected value of the number of rounds you will need to finish the game?

*My thoughts so far*:

Every outcome of the game corresponds to a unique increasing sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{m - 1}, n$, where $m$ is the number of rounds needed to finish the game. We have $2^{n - 1}$ possible sequences, which are not equally likely. We can quickly see this by noting that the sequence ${n}$ has a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$, while the sequence ${1, 2, \ldots, n}$ has a probability of $\frac{1}{n!}$.

The probability of an arbitrary sequence $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_{m - 1}, m$ is thus $\frac{1}{n (x_1 - 1)  (x_2 - 1)  \cdots (x_{m - 1} - 1)}$

Theoretically, this gives us $P(m) = \sum \frac{1}{n (x_1 - 1) (x_2 - 1)  \cdots (x_{m - 1} - 1)}$, which could then be used to derive the expected value. But I haven't figured out a nice way to express this sum, and I suspect there must be a more elegant approach.

I also considered an alternate approach. Let $X_1$ be the number of rounds we need to pass the first card, $X_2$ be the number of *additional* rounds we need to surpass the second card after we've already surpassed the first card, and so on, where $X_i$ is the number of additional rounds we need to pass the ith card after we've already passed the $i-1$th card, for indexes $1 \leq i \leq n - 1$.

Each random variable $X_i$ is Bernoulli, with value 0 if the we never land on card $i$, and with value 1 if we do land on card $i$ (requiring an extra hop to then jump over it). From here, we have

\begin{align*}
E(m) &= E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_{n - 1})\\
        &= P\text{(Stop on Card 1)} + P\text{(Stop on Card 2)} + \cdots + P\text{(Stop on Card $n - 1$)}
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, I'm afraid I'm stuck here.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: I'd let $E(n)$ be the answer for $n$ cards. $E(1)=0$, $E(2)=1$, $E(3)=(1/2)((E(2)+1)+(E(1)+1))=3/2$. Maybe calculate a few more, and look for a pattern?

Comment: Big hint: Let $r_n$ be the expected number of rounds to finish the game when there are $n$ cards. Notice that $r_n=1+\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}r_k$. Notice that $r_n=H_{n-1}$ (the $(n-1)$-st Harmonic numbers) are a solution to that recurrence.

Comment: Looks like I might as well write a full answer...

Comment: @C-RAM It was very clear to me after this comment, thanks for the hint and for the full solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n$ denote the random variable associated with the number of rounds when there are $n$ cards. By computing the first few values of $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ we may conjecture a closed form involving the [harmonic numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#:%7E:text=The%20harmonic%20number%20Hn,decrease%20monotonically%20towards%20the%20limit):

$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1n$$

To prove this, note that $\mathbb{E}[X_n|\text{The first card is } n-k]=1+\mathbb{E}[X_k]$, so by the [law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),

$$\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X_n|\text{The first card is } n-k]=1+\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[X_k]$$

Now, all that remains is to show that

$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_{k-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{m=1}^{k-1}\frac1m\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}\frac{n-m-1}{m}\\
&=(n-1)H_{n-2}-(n-2)\\
&=(n-1)H_{n-1}-(n-1)\\
H_{n-1}&=1+\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}H_{k-1}
\end{split}$$

Since $H_{n-1}$ satisfies the same recurrence as $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ and $H_0=0=\mathbb{E}[X_1]$, then $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=H_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 1$, as desired.